# Javascript (Resize when browser window is over 436px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, responsive

I will try to explain in details what I want, since it's hard to explain how I want it to be.
I've created a responsive website, where I want to show 3 boxes:

(Day 1 - Day 2 - Day 3)

[See image how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soN8m.png)

The issue (Try this and U will see what is my issue:

1. Resize the screen window to less then 436px (So u get the red boxes)
2. Then click on Day 2, which then opens the content of Day 2
3. Start to resize the browser (This will then close the box "Day 2"
   automatically. I dont want it to close when I resize.

The reason why I have created the resize, was for the desktop, so it was expanding all the boxes when seen on desktop.

**MY CODE:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        if($(window).width()<436)
      $('.bbottom2').hide();
      $('.btop').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $menuItem = $(this).next('.bbottom, .bbottom2');
        $menuItem.slideToggle();
      });
 });
 
 
      $( window ).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width()>436) $('.bbottom, .bbottom2').show();
        else $('.bbottom2').hide();
      });
```

```css
.ticket{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
}

.btop2, .btop{
  background-color:grey;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.btop:hover{
  background-color:darkgrey;
}

/*Responsive*/
@media screen and (max-width: 436px) {

.ticket{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:none;
}

.btop{
  background-color:red;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
  
  

.btop:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ticket">
    <div class="btop">Day 1</div>
    <div class="bbottom">Price 20</div>
</div>

<div class="ticket">
    <div class="btop">Day 2</div>
    <div class="bbottom2">Price 99</div>
</div>

<div class="ticket">
    <div class="btop">Day 3</div>
    <div class="bbottom2">Price 149</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not do this with CSS media queries?

Comment: @Pointy CSS doesnt have an onclick event handler.

Comment: Well yes, of course the "click" part has to be JavaScript, but the screen width visibility rules can be CSS.

Comment: @Pointy Can you show how you would do?

Comment: [MDN article on using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `$menuItem.toggleClass( "bbottom2" );` to the `.btop` button 
and add also `bbottom` class to other ticket

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        if($(window).width()<436)
      $('.bbottom2').hide();
      $('.btop').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $menuItem = $(this).next('.bbottom, .bbottom2');
        
        $menuItem.slideToggle();
        $menuItem.toggleClass( "bbottom2" );
      });
 });
 
 
      $( window ).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width()>436) $('.bbottom, .bbottom2').show();
        else $('.bbottom2').hide();
      });
```

```css
.ticket{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:left;
}

.btop2, .btop{
  background-color:grey;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.btop:hover{
  background-color:darkgrey;
}

/*Responsive*/
@media screen and (max-width: 436px) {

.ticket{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  float:none;
}

.btop{
  background-color:red;
  pointer-events:auto;
}
  
  

.btop:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ticket">
    <div class="btop">Day 1</div>
    <div class="bbottom">Price 20</div>
</div>

<div class="ticket">
    <div class="btop">Day 2</div>
    <div class="bbottom bbottom2">Price 99</div>
</div>

<div class="ticket">
    <div class="btop">Day 3</div>
    <div class="bbottom bbottom2">Price 149</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it works, but now when I try to click on it again, it doesnt close. Can you fix that plzzz?

Comment: I ' made a mistake at first , i've post double answer try to refresh the page and see my new answer .

Comment: I just tried the code. It works with the resizing perfectly. But when I click on Day 2 and then try to close it again, then it doesnt close.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the resize code. Because it is hidding the boxes right away, when you resize the browser window. It is as if javascript is not detecting when it surpasses 436px.

Comment: Hi , it works fine !! 
please be sure that you've added the `bbottom` class to all ticket div as mentioned in my answer  so "day2" to would be like 

    `<div class="btop">Day 2</div>
    <div class=
    "bbottom bbottom2">Price 99</div> `

Comment: Yes it works :) Sorry just me who isnt reading carefully. Thanks very much bro!

Comment: gotta up +1... :-)

Comment: It doesnt allow me to give u a +1

(Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.)